# jmeter cannot load/find all files/templates / working with angular

Tags: angularjs, jmeter, load-testing

When I start jmeter, I get in "result tree" all files (js, css, html, ..), 
assuming they are listed in head of html. 
But all other files (my templates), which will be loaded depending in ng-controller (e.g. footer.html, content.html, header.html, login.html) cannot be loaded by jmeter. Why ?

I have searched for solution but I didn't find something useful. Is there a special angular setting in jmeter needed? Who can help me on this?

```
<head>   <!-- these files can be loaded by jmeter -->

    <script src="js/lib/xxxxxx.js"></script>    
    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
 <!-- and other files -->
</head>


<div id="_wrapper"> <!-- following files cannot be loaded by jmeter -->
        <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
        <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl" ng-include="'navigation.html'"></nav>
        <section class="content" ng-view></section>
        <footer ng-controller="FooterCtrl" ng-include="'footer.html'"></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular JS is javascript framework. JMeter will not execute any JS library.

Also,

As per http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Jmeter downloads only these when you select 'download all embedded resources'

```
images
applets
stylesheets
external scripts
frames, iframes
background images (body, table, TD, TR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "**Retrieve All Embedded Resources**" at the bottom of your HTTP sampler.

Run the test again and see.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks. It was checked already. But the files cannot be loaded.